# How to add default string to attribute during CoreData migration

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a simple Coredata program for cataloging some data - coded in Objective-C. A new model version was created that has a new attribute. A mapping model has been created, it is not inferred. The migration is working great, however, after migration the new attribute is empty - which is expected. I would like to add a placeholder string value to the new attribute during the migration process.
The two thoughts I have is to either place custom code in the value expression of the mapping model or subclass `NSMigrationPolicy` and add code there, but I have not found much information regarding either. Any suggestions?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Have you tried a constant value expression in the mapping model? For example `"placeholder"`.

Comment: @Willeke - Several months ago I tried added a simple string as you suggested, however, I kept getting errors. I couldn't figure out what was wrong, so I abandoned the idea. After reading your comment, I decided to try again and it actual worked this time. I have no idea why this didn’t work originally, apparently I was doing something wrong. Sometimes we all need a little hint/push, I appreciate the comment, it got me to try again. I’d be happy to give you credit if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Value Expression in the mapping model can be a constant value expression like string `"placeholder"` or integer `1`.